# Drupal 7 : How to associate a taxonomy term to an uploaded file

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

How to associate a taxonomy term to an uploaded file with drupal 7 ? For example I add a node with a file type field, and upload a file then i try to associate a taxonomy term to the uploaded file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't attach a taxonomy term to a field, it's against the Drupal data structure. You can :

- attach a term to your node, adding a term reference field beside your file field,
- create a content type holding your file field, a term reference field, and an entity reference field pointing on to your regular nodes (i.e creating a separate content type for your file field + the term reference, and set up a relation between your regular nodes and this content type). Best solution in my opinion : if you need to attach terms to your files, then they deserve a content type.

You will need [Entity Reference module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) for the second solution. Views allows you to grab related content ("Relationships" in advanced tab) when displaying the regular nodes.

Comment: thanks but can you give me an example please ? I have a node Document with 2 file uploaded like this : Document : File1, File2 and i have a taxonomy Structure when i create a document i upload the two files and associate them with two different structrure for example : Document : File1-Structure1 and File2-Structure2.

Comment: I give you an example. Thanks.